# Constructing a circular diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]
Can someone construct this image as I have no idea how to start.

Thank you.

Comment: (i) select package for drawing images (TikZ, PStricks, ...) with which you are familiar, (ii) se example of images in answers here on site or in some home pages with collected solutions (as is https://texample.net/)

Comment: I couldn't find a solution on circular diagrams with items on the boundary

Comment: Well, there is small chance that already exist aa solution exactly what you like to have, but there are plenty similar images. You need to draw three circles, add to them what is on circles (it is not readable from your sketch, sory) and ask for help where you stuck.

Comment: i need a circle cut equally in 3 parts labelled A,B and C with objects(circular and 'x') in the cut circumference. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As starting point, with `tikz` (about which I'm a bit familiar):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm and 11mm,
     C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=#1},
   C/.default = 24mm,
every label/.append style = {inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\node (a) [C]   {};
% elements of the top circle named "a"
    \foreach \i in {30, 150, 270}
        \draw (a.center)  ++ (\i:9mm) -- ++ (\i:6mm); 
    \node[font=\Large, label= above:A, label=below:1]   at (a.90) {$\times$};
    \node[C=2mm, label=210:B, label=30:2]   at (a.210) {};
    \node[C=2mm, label=330:C,label=150:3]   at (a.330) {};
%
\node (b) [C, below  left=of a]  {};
\node (c) [C, below right=of a]  {};
%
\draw[very thick, -Straight Barb]   ([yshift=-4mm] a.south) -- ++ (0,-7mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above MWE (Minimal Working Example) produce:

[image]

In part of image code below is intended to draw circles and crosses on the top circle (they are not well visible in your sketch), so probably you need to adopt them to what you like to have. Similar You can add to other two circles. If you will suck with this, not hesitate to ask for help.

Comment: yeah, I'm terrible at this so I would appreciate your help